# Adding additional form post fields to a mysql insert script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have been doing a tutorial on posting to a database with Ajax and now I have it working with 1 form field, but I would like to learn how to get it to work with 2 form fields.

The form field I have working is named `content_txt` and it is inserted into `add_delete_record(content)`. The second form is named `balance_txt` and would also be inserted in the same table as `content_txt` was.

This is the block of code that I'm trying to figure out how to update with the extra form field. I have added notes in it to explain what I am using each thing for and what I want to do:

```
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0) 
{   //checks $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty, but I am not sure how to add the other field into this


    $contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
//using this to strip stuff from the post, but I am not sure how I should added the other form field to this, should I create another variable line or can I add it to this.

    // Insert sanitize string in record and I think I have it correct, except if I need to add a variable following content
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(`content`,`balance`) VALUES('".$contentToSave."')"))
    {

         //This returns the results back to the page, do I need to have a duplicate section for the additional record or will this work like a loop.
          $my_id = mysql_insert_id(); //Get ID of last inserted row from MySQL
          echo '<li id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
          echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$my_id.'">';
          echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
          echo '</a></div>';
          echo $contentToSave.'</li>';
          mysql_close($connecDB); //close db connection
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use two form just named same field name "content_txt" and post it .

or when you ajax data change it name on ajax field .

Comment: HI, I did not see that someone responded to this question, but I have a new question with more information regarding this at, but the two answers given did not work.  Here is a link to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123567/how-to-modify-php-jquery-ajax-script-to-have-more-than-one-form-field-posst